# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}\,\mathrm dx= \frac{2}{\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}\,\mathrm dx= \frac{2}{\pi}$$
with $a > 0$.

Actually I already know how to do it with the residue theorem:

First we notice that we can instead calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}\,\mathrm dx,$$
and take the imaginary part in the end.

Let $\gamma$ be a contour from $-R $ to $R$ on the real axis and then back to the starting point following a semicircle in the upper half of the complex plane. But because $f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}}{z(\pi^2-a^2z^2)}$ has poles at $0$ and $\pm\frac{\pi}{a}$ we can't integrate over that contour. So we indent the contour with small semicircles of radius $\epsilon$ so that the poles are excluded from the region traced out by the contour. By then letting $R \rightarrow \infty$ it can be shown that the integral of $f$ along the large semicircle vanishes. And by $\epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ the desired integral is approached. The integration of the small semicircles turns out to be given by
$$-\pi i \left(\operatorname{Res}\left(f, -\frac{\pi}{a}\right) +  \operatorname{Res}(f, 0) + \operatorname{Res}\left(f, \frac{\pi}{a}\right)\right),$$
with $\operatorname{Res}\left(f, \pm \frac{\pi}{a}\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}$ and $\operatorname{Res}(f, 0) = \frac{1}{\pi^2}$. Since the contour traced by $\gamma$ contains no poles, it follows from here, that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}\,\mathrm dx = i\frac{2}{\pi}.$$
Taking the imaginary part we get the result.

But when I first saw this problem I tried to directly apply the residue theorem to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$ which appeared simpler to me, but I got a wrong result. In this case the singularities of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(az)}{z(\pi^2-a^2z^2)}$ are removable. So, I assumed the whole process of the indentation of the contour is not necessary. And so, the contour consists just of the path along the real axis and the (large) semicircle. Still, the integral over the semicircle vanishes, and the contour contains no poles so the whole integral along the contour is $0$. This means that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(\pi^2-a^2x^2)}dx$ itself has to equal $0$, which of course is a contradiction to the result above.

What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose $\sin(ax)$ does not go to $0$ on the big circle

Comment: Why the integral on semi-circle vanishes, $e^{iax}$ is a exp function after all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325440/computation-real-integral-with-residue-theorem/4325481#4325481

Comment: The integral on the semi-circle vanishes because: $\left |\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp(iaRe^{it})}{Re^{it}(\pi^2-a^2R^2e^{2it})} iRe^{it} dt \right | 
\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \left |\frac{\exp(iaRe^{it})}{\pi^2-a^2R^2e^{2it}} \right | dt   
\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp(-aRsin(t))}{\pi^2} dt  
\leq \frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \exp(-aR\frac{2t}{\pi}) dt =$  $\frac{1}{\pi aR}(1-e^{-aR})$ ,

which goes to zero for $R \rightarrow \infty$. I would argue the same argument holds for $sin(ax)$ since $|sin(ax)| \leq |e^{iax}|$.